# How do I add a meta tag when creating a node via REST API?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

So I have this code, using Guzzle POSTing to create node via Drupal REST API.
No error, but the `field_meta_tags` value is empty  on the node created (still using default `[node:summary]` for the meta description).

```
$node = array(
'title' => array(0 => array('value' => 'asd')),
'type' => array(0 => array('target_id' => 'page')),
'path' => array(0 => array('alias' => $pathalias)),
'field_meta_tags' => array(
  'title' => 'asd',
  'description' => 'asd',
  'keywords' => 'asd',
),
'body' => array(0 => array('value' => 'huehuehue')),
);

$response = $client->post($base_url . '/entity/node', array(
  'cookies' => $jar,
  'query' => array(
    '_format' => 'json',
  ),
  'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-Token' => $csrf_token,
  ),
  'json' => $node
));
```

I also try using array structure like this:

```
'field_meta_tags' => array(0 => array(
  'title' => 'asd',
  'description' => 'asd',
  'keywords' => 'asd,
)),
```

But still no luck.

What is the correct format to provide metatag value? Or is there another thing that I might need to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copy/paste the following snippets from the readme file of the metatag module.
I can see that you are missing the serialize function in your solution.
Hopefully that helps you.

```
Programmatically assign meta tags to an entity
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are two ways to assign an entity's meta tags in custom module. Both
scenarios require a "Metatag" field be added to the entity's field settings, the
field name "field_meta_tags" is used but this is completely arbitrary.

Option 1:

  $entity_type = 'node';
  $values = [
    'nid' => NULL,
    'type' => 'article',
    'title' => 'Testing metatag creation',
    'uid' => 1,
    'status' => TRUE,
    'field_meta_tags' => serialize([
      'title' => 'Some title',
      'description' => 'Some description.',
      'keywords' => 'Some,Keywords',
    ]),
  ];
  $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->create($values);
  $node->save();

Option 2:

  $node = Node::create(array(
    'type' => article,
    'langcode' => 'en',
    'status' => 1,
    'uid' => 1,
  ));
  $node->set('title', 'Testing metatag creation');
  $node->set('field_meta_tags', serialize([
    'title' => 'Some title',
    'description' => 'Some description.',
    'keywords' => 'Some,Keywords',
  ]));
  $node->save();

In both examples, the custom meta tag values will still be merged with the
values defined via the global defaults prior to being output - it is not
necessary to copy each value to the new record.
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it. Value needs to be serialized. `'field_meta_tags' => array(0 => array(
  'value' => serialize(array(
    'title' => 'asd',
    'description' => 'asd',
    'keywords' => 'asd',
  )),
)),`

Comment: I am glad it worked. 
Best regards,
Oleg

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been trying many ways to do it so far! May I ask how did you figure it out? How do you usually find out how to update fields programmatically?